# IE8 jQuery $(el).attr('style') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, internet-explorer-8

I need to pull the entire string of the inline style that is embedded within tags. This works for Chrome, but fails on IE8. Any ideas? Here is the a sample markup that I am working with.

```
<div class="thumbnail-no-border pull-left">
  <img alt="Issue #917" class="" src="/assets/original/917.jpg?14" style="width: 700px; height: 467px;">
</div>
```

I'm using it in the following context:

```
$('img').each(function(index, el){  
        console.log( $(el).attr('style')  );
});
```

This works in the following fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e6zvkeLv/ , just not inside IE

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code? Can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Since you selected jQuery 2.1 in the fiddle, [jQuery 2.x does not support IE8.](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) You will need to use 1.x.

Comment: Thanks. I made the switch and it's working :)